# Integration by parts Green's formula

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to do some kind of integration by parts to $$\int{f(\nabla g \cdot \nabla h)}$$
We know Green's identity holds with $f \equiv 1$.  Is there a nice expression with general $f$?  Let's say everything here is smooth so the integrals and derivatives make sense.

Comment: downvote... why?

Answer (score 1):

One might note that $\nabla g \cdot \nabla h = \nabla \cdot (g \nabla h) - g \Delta h$. Not sure where to go from here, but this might be a start.

Comment: In fact, that actually was exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm interested to know what you ended up with?

Comment: I'm dealing with functions that are $0$ on the boundary anyways, so do green's identity in vector form (choose $f\nabla g$ and $\nabla h$), then apply your identity.  This moves derivatives off of the function I wanted to get them off of.

Comment: You need $f \nabla g$ to be the gradient of some function, right? Of what function is it the gradient? (I'm just learning this stuff, too...)

Comment: I'm using $\int_{U} (\psi \nabla \cdot \bf{\Gamma} + \bf{\Gamma}\cdot \nabla \psi)  dV = \oint_{\partial U}{\psi \bf{(\Gamma \cdot n})}ds$